# Implicit localization and embedded resource

Tags: asp.net, localization, resx

Can we use implicit localization in asp.net (meta:resourcekey) while using an embedded resource file (resx)?

If the resources in app_localresouces are set to "content" everything works but I can't get it to work if I set it to "embedded".

Is it possible to do so while using implicit localization?

Comment: Might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24413709).